# Regular expression (.+?) in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am used to Regex in Java, but was confused when I saw them used in JMeter at https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=SVxB3Tk4O4A#t=430

What does (.+?) mean?
Is there a difference between regex (.+?) and (.*)?

Is JMeter regex "$1$" the equivalent to Java regex "$1"?
According to Apache Regex (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), it appears to be the same. Is that true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference between regex (.+?) and (.*)?

**Lazy** way

```
.+?      any character except \n (1 or more times 
             (matching the least amount possible))
```

**Greedy** way

```
.*       any character except \n (0 or more times   
            (matching the most amount possible))
```

---

In other words:

1. `.+?` matches any character (except newline)

   Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed *[lazy]*
2. `.*` matches any character (except newline)

   Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed *[greedy]*

I think [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) uses [Perl5 regular expressions](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/api/org/apache/oro/text/regex/package-summary.html).